Custom number format based on a cell value?
I have a cell where a number is entered and a drop down menu with three options; PERCENT, NUMBER, and CURRENCY.
Whatever selection I choose from the drop down, I want it to apply custom formatting based on the following table:



Selection
Format




PERCENT
0%


NUMBER
_(* #,##0_);_(* (#,##0);_(* "-"??_);_(@_)


CURRENCY
_($* #,##0_);_($* (#,##0);_($* "-"??_);_(@_)



Say I enter the number 27...
If PERCENT is selected, 27 will be formatted as 2700%
If NUMBER is selected, 27 will be formatted as 27
If CURRENCY is selected, 27 will be formatted as $27
The purpose of this is to keep the formatting in a chart. I want these formats to be kept when I select "Linked to source", which doesn't appear to work when I use conditional formatting so that's off the table.

For Percent make it #% like this instead of 0% and I found it to be working, I have used =TEXT(C7,XLOOKUP(B8,B3:B5,C3:C5,";;")) where C7 is the selection type and B3:B5 is the Selection Column while C3:C5 is the Format Column also, when there is nothing i have used ;;

Use a Worksheet_Change macro to set the formatting.
For example, if your dropdown is in G2 and your column to apply the formatting is Column D, then:
(Note: The below formats the entire column in accord with the dropdown selection, and will change it if you change the selection. If you just want to format the individual cell when you enter a value, then some minor changes will be required)
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rg As Range, c As Range
    
Set rg = Columns(4) 'column D
If Target = [G2] Then
    With rg
        Select Case [G2]
            Case "NUMBER"
                .NumberFormat = "_(* #,##0_);_(* (#,##0);_(* "" - ""??_);_(@_)"
            Case "PERCENT"
                .NumberFormat = "0%"
            Case "CURRENCY"
                .NumberFormat = "_($* #,##0_);_($* (#,##0);_($* "" - ""??_);_(@_)"
            Case Else
                .NumberFormat = "General"
        End Select
    End With
  End If
End Sub

To enter this event-triggered Macro, right click on the sheet tab.
Select "View Code" from the right-click drop-down menu.
Then paste the code into the window that opens.
